# Two envelopes problem: is exchanging envelopes always a Bayes-Nash equilibrium?

Tags: calculus, probability, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider the following problem:

> Suppose $f: [0; \infty) \to [0; \infty)$ is a continuous bijection. Suppose two people are given two envelopes with $x \$ $ and $f(x) \$ $ respectively. They know the value of $f$ and the amount of money in their envelope (but do not know, whether this is $x$ or $f(x)$). They consider getting $x \$ $ and $f(x) \$ $ to be equally likely. Then they are allowed to request exchange of envelopes (and if they both do, the envelopes are exchanged between them). Is the situation, where both of them request the exchange, always a Bayes-Nash equilibrium?

First, note that the game is symmetric.

Then, suppose, a player got $y$ in their envelope. Then, they consider the amount of money in another players envelope to be either $f(y)$ (in case, when $y = x$) or $f^{-1}(y)$ in case ($y = f(x)$) with equal probability. Thus the expected gain in case when both request exchange is $\frac{f(y) + f^{-1}(y)}{2}$ and $y$, if at least some of them refuses. Thus our question is equivalent to the following problem:

> Suppose $f: [0; \infty) \to [0; \infty)$ is a continuous bijection and $y \in [0; \infty)$. Is it always true, that $f(y) + f^{-1}(y) \geq 2y$?

I managed to solve this problem (with positive answer) only for the case when $f$ is linear. Indeed, if $f(x) \equiv cx$ for $c \in (0 ; \infty)$, then $f(y) + f^{-1}(y) - 2y = cy + c^{-1}y - 2y = c^{-1}y(c - 1)^2 \geq 0$. However, I do not know, whether this method can be generalised to an arbitrary $f$...

Comment: “They consider getting $x$ and $f(x)$ to be equally likely.” There are multiple issues with this statement. Until it is translated into a mathematically well-defined statement, the problem cannot be considered mathematically well-posed.

Comment: @JohnBentin, suppose envelopes are numerated as 0 and 1. In the envelop with number 0 there are $x \$ $ and in the envelope with number 1 there are $f(x) \$ $. Players do not know the number on their envelope, but suppose that it is 0 with probability $0.5$ and 1 with probability $0.5$

Comment: I'm sorry, I omitted the dollar symbol, thinking it to be a typo. A quantity $x$ of dollars is never written $x\$$: it is always $\$x$, where $x$ is normally allowed to be only a multiple of $\frac1{100}$. Thus you cannot have $\$\pi$ or $\$\frac13$. This restriction applies equally to $f(x)$. Your conditions on $f$ entail that it is strictly monotonic. It follows that neither $x$ nor $f(x)$ can be $0$. Whence neither can be $0.01$, $0.02$, ... , $314,\!159,\!625.35$, ... . Even if you allow any real quantity of dollars, other issues kick in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not always true. If $f(y)=\sqrt y$, then $f(.5)+f^{-1}(.5)-2\times .5=\sqrt{\frac 12}+\frac 1 4 - 1<0.$